# Prove $\frac{5i}{2+i}=1+2i$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

Since $5i=5e^{i \frac{\pi}{2}}$
And $2+i=\sqrt{5}e^{ix_1}$ where $x_1=\arctan \frac{1}{2}$, we have $\frac{5i}{2+i}=\sqrt{5}[\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-x_1)+i\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-x_1)]$
Now from here how do I continue?

P.s:I know how to solve this if it wasn't asked to solve using polar forms.

Comment: Multiply top and bottom by $2-i$ then use the difference of two squares.

Comment: You don't have to use polar form, do you?

Comment: First, there's an error. It's $\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-x_2)$ not $\frac{\pi}{3}-x_1$. Second, if you need to use polar forms, use $\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-\alpha)=\sin\alpha$ and $\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-\alpha)=\cos \alpha$.

Comment: If you specifically have to use the exponential forms, I suggest you split up the cosines and sines using the sum and difference rules. If you don't have to use the polar forms, don't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using polar form (with exponential notation for convenience),

$\frac{5i}{2+i}=\frac{5e^{i\frac{\pi}2}}{\sqrt 5 e^{i \arctan \frac 12}} = \sqrt 5 e^{i(\frac {\pi}2 - \arctan \frac 12)} = \sqrt 5 \cos (\frac {\pi}2 - \arctan \frac 12) + i \sqrt 5\sin (\frac {\pi}2 - \arctan \frac 12)$

Sketch the $1,2,\sqrt 5$ right triangle and determine that the cosine of the relevant angle (which is complementary to the angle with tangent $\frac 12$) is $\frac 1{\sqrt 5}$ and its sine is $\frac 2{\sqrt 5}$. The result above immediately simplifies to $1+2i$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$\begin{align}
\cos\left({\pi \over 2}-x\right)&=\sin{x}\\
\sin\left({\pi \over 2}-x\right)&=\cos{x}\\
\tan\left({\pi \over 2}-x\right)&={1\over\tan{x}}
\end{align}$$

So now let's develop the hint from where you left it i.e

$${5i\over 1+2i}=\sqrt{5}\left(\cos\left({\pi\over 2}-x\right)+i\sin\left({\pi\over 2}-x\right)\right)=a+ib$$

So $a^2+b^2=5$ and

$${b\over a}=\tan\left({\pi\over 2}-x\right)={1\over \tan{x}}=2$$

And so $5a^2=5$ and $a=\pm 1$, $b=\pm 2$ The negative solutions are to be excluded  because $0\lt {\pi\over 2}-x\lt {\pi\over 2}$

Answer (score 1):

You have\begin{align}\frac{5i}{2+i}&=\sqrt5\exp\left(\left(\frac\pi2-\arctan\left(\frac12\right)\right)i\right)\\&=\sqrt5\left(\cos\left(\frac\pi2-\arctan\left(\frac12\right)\right)+\sin\left(\frac\pi2-\arctan\left(\frac12\right)\right)i\right)\\&=\sqrt5\left(\sin\left(\arctan\left(\frac12\right)\right)+\cos\left(\arctan\left(\frac12\right)\right)i\right).\end{align}Now, note that\begin{align}\frac{\cos\left(\arctan\left(\frac12\right)\right)}{\sin\left(\arctan\left(\frac12\right)\right)}&=\cot\left(\arctan\left(\frac12\right)\right)\\&=\frac1{\tan\left(\arctan\left(\frac12\right)\right)}\\&=2.\end{align}Therefore,\begin{align}\frac{5i}{2+i}&=\sqrt5\exp\left(\arctan\left(2\right)i\right)\\&=\sqrt5\left(\frac1{\sqrt5}+\frac2{\sqrt5}i\right)\\&=1+2i.\end{align}

Comment: I think you "reversed" the starting and ending points a bit. Not that it matters, you can rearrange your result in one step. Just looks a bit weird.

Comment: @Deepak Sure. I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: How did you get the equality after "Therefore,"?

Comment: @Maxence1402 I had previously obtained that$$\frac{5i}{2+i}=\sqrt5(a+bi),$$with $a^2+b^2=1$ and $\frac ba=2$. But then$$a+bi=\cos\left(\arctan(2)\right)+\sin\left(\arctan(2)\right)i=\frac1{\sqrt5}+\frac2{\sqrt5}i.$$

Answer (score 1):

Even in complex analysis, if $z_1 \neq 0$, then

$\displaystyle \frac{z_3}{z_1} = z_2 \iff (z_1 \times z_2) = z_3.$

$\displaystyle (2 + i) \times (1 + 2i) = 5i.$

Answer (score 0):

We already have $ LHS =\sqrt 5 e^{i(\frac{\pi}{2}-x_1)}, x_1 =\arctan \frac{1}{2} \tag 1$.

Continue with $RHS=1+2i=\sqrt 5 e^{ix_2}, x_2=\arctan 2 \tag 2$.

$x_1, x_2$ are complementary angles, $x_2= \frac{\pi}{2}-x_1 \to LHS=RHS$

Note: polar form represented by exponential form for simplicity in (1)(2). There is no difference between two forms since $r$ and $\theta$ are same for LHS and RHS.